# Blueimp Jquery upload files to 2 servers

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

i am working with https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/ Plugin.

and its works great!
i am tring to change the plugin\options some how to allow with the same click on upload button to send each image to 2 servers with CORS.

any idea how to send each image in the list to both of the servers?

Comment: Hard to answer without the code you are using. Have you tried calling the upload a second time in the click handler?

Comment: i am using the same code as the demo use, with the ui. i tried to read and understand what they did in the fileupload-ui.js, but without any success